# Erro no JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Alguém poderia me dizer como fazer o JOIN para preencher os dados automaticamente a partir do campo descrição. Acusa este erro `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\function.php on line 9
{"codigo_produto":"","barcode":"","porcao":""}` no caso a linha 9 é esta `if($resultado->num_rows){`

index.php

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("input[name='descri']").blur(function(){
                            var $codigo_produto = $("input[name='codigo_produto']");
                            var $barcode = $("input[name='barcode']");
                            var $codigo_tipo = $("input[name='codigo_tipo']");
                            var $porcao = $("input[name='porcao']");

                            $.getJSON('function.php',{ 
                                    descricao: $( this ).val() 
                            },function( json ){
                                    $codigo_produto.val( json.codigo_produto );
                                    $barcode.val( json.barcode );
                                    $codigo_tipo.val ( json.val );
//                                    $porcao.val ( json.val );
                            });
                    });
            });
            </script>   
            <div class="col-lg-5"><!-- Inicio Input Cóodigo do Produto-->
                <label for="ex1">Descrição:</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="13" name="descri"><br>
            </div><!-- Fim Input Código do Produto -->
            <div class="col-lg-4"><!-- Inicio Input Cóodigo do Produto-->
                <label for="ex1">Código do Produto:</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="13" name="codigo_produto"><br>
            </div><!-- Fim Input Código do Produto -->

            <div class="col-lg-5"><!-- Inicio Input Código EAN / Barcode -->
                <label for="ex1">Código EAN:</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="13" name="barcode"><br>
            </div><!-- Fim Input Código EAN / Barcode -->          

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label for="ex1">Tipo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo_tipo" value="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label for="ex1">Porção:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="20"  name="porcao">
            </div>
    </body>
```

function.php

```
   function retorna($descricao, $conn){

        $result = "SELECT a.descricao, a.codigo_produto, a.barcode, b.codigo_tipo, c.porcao FROM CADPRO A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOPROD B ON (A.CODIGO_PRODUTO = B.CODIGO_PRODUTO)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN INFOPROD C ON (B.CODIGO_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO_PRODUTO) WHERE descricao =";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

        if(!is_null($resultado)){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                $valores['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
                $valores['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
                $codigo_produto = $row['codigo_produto'];                    
                $valores['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
                $valores['porcao'] = $row['porcao'];
        } else {
                $valores['codigo_produto'] = '';
                $valores['barcode'] = '';
                $valors['tipo'] = '';
                $valores['porcao'] = '';             
        }

        return json_encode($valores);                
    }
    if(isset($_GET['descricao'])){
        echo retorna($_GET['descricao'], $conn);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Defiz a edição, senão a resposta dada perderia o sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não tem sentido:

```
if(!is_null($resultado)){
```

O `mysqli_query` nunca vai retornar `NULL`, ele sempre vai cair no mesmo if, mesmo que dê erro, no caso ele retornou `false` e como `false` não é `null` ele entra no primeiro if de qualquer jeito, mas o `mysqli_fetch_assoc` sempre espera um "objeto".

Pra evitar isso é só **sempre usar a documentação** pra ter certeza de como a função funciona e vai ver http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues.

Veja a documentação dize que ele retorna `FALSE` se falhar ou um *objeto* `mysqli_result` se tiver sucesso.

Mude o código para:

```
if($resultado){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
        $valores['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
        $codigo_produto = $row['codigo_produto'];                    
        $valores['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
        $valores['porcao'] = $row['porcao'];
} else {
```

Outra sugestão é criar um JSON de erro, assim:

```
if($resultado){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
        $valores['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
        $codigo_produto = $row['codigo_produto'];                    
        $valores['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
        $valores['porcao'] = $row['porcao'];
} else {
       return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));
}
```

Outro de importante, você não declarou a variavel $valores, mas declarou a variavel `$codigo_produto = $row['codigo_produto'];`, mas você não esta usando ela, talvez o código deva ficar assim:

```
function retorna($descricao, $conn){

    $result = "SELECT a.descricao, a.codigo_produto, a.barcode, b.codigo_tipo, c.porcao FROM CADPRO A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOPROD B ON (A.CODIGO_PRODUTO = B.CODIGO_PRODUTO)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN INFOPROD C ON (B.CODIGO_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO_PRODUTO) WHERE descricao =";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    if(!is_null($resultado)){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['codigo_produto'] = $row['codigo_produto'];
        $valores['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
        $codigo_produto = $row['codigo_produto'];                    
        $valores['codigo_tipo'] = $row['codigo_tipo'];
        $valores['porcao'] = $row['porcao'];
    } else {
        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
    }

    return json_encode($valores);                
}
```

Comment: No caso o seu código apresenta este erro ao debugar ---> <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: valores in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\function.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />

Comment: @VictorT. isso ae já é outro erro, é só vc observar, vc não declarou a variavel $valores dentro do escopo da função. E se vc notar bem vc declarou a variavel `$codigo_produto`, mas não esta usando ela.

Comment: @VictorT. Editei a resposta, veja o codigo de exemplo do final se dá pra vc entender.

Comment: então no caso, eu acho estranho o fato de eu testar o mesmo código sem join utilizando ele pra trazer dados de uma única tabela e funciona, estranho isso, vou editar a pergunta o arquivo funcition.php para verificar, está identico

Comment: @VictorT. uma coisa não tem nada haver com a outra, join é no comando do mysql, teus erros eram no PHP, veja a edição da resposta ........ Se quer entender o básico do JOIN leia isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/3635

Comment: o problema não é o JOIN mesmo, mas muito estranho o PHP não reconhecer, já que eu jogo esse JOIN no MYSQL e funciona

Comment: @VictorT. não é isso, PHP é PHP, mysql é mysql... eles não trabalham paralelamente, o problema é como vc esta fazendo o JOIN que vai gerar uma saida diferente, como eu te mandei no linkp pra vc entender, cada join tem um efeito, entendendo o efeito vc já entende parte do resultado, se jogar em um programa como HeidSQL ou phpmyadmin vai notar que provavelmente ele gerou linhas repetidas, ou seja é você que não esta entendendo bem o efeito do JOIN e esta fazendo confusão, a culpa não é do PHP.....

Comment: ....  Provavelmente você vai querer somar valores ou agrupar algo, ae não tenho como te responder porque não sei como é tua tabela nem os dados que contem nela. @VictorT.

Comment: eu quero que a partir da descrição que o usuário digite, a medida que ele de tab os dados restantes sejam preenchidos automaticamente

Comment: @VictorT. ae vc já está mudando o sentido da pergunta totalmente, eu resolvi o problema aqui, certo? A parte que era o erro `Trying to get property of non-object`. Agora se tem outra duvida ainda mais sendo complexa assim crie uma nova pergunta e explique detalhadamente o que ocorre.

Comment: não meu problema continua, mas vou marcar sua resposta como a melhor mesmo assim pelo esforço, BASTA VOCÊ LER A PERGUNTA --->Alguém poderia me dizer como fazer o JOIN para preencher os dados automaticamente a partir do campo descrição.

Comment: @VictorT. continua a mesma mensagem de erro `Trying to get property of non-object` ou `Undefined variable: valores`?

Comment: o erro agora é ----><b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\function.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
{"codigo_produto":null,"barcode":null,"codigo_tipo":null,"porcao":null} MAS EDITEI MINHA FUNCTION E ESTA IDENTICO A SUA, SE EU TIRO O !is_null ME RETORNA APENAS [] no NETWORK

Comment: @VictorT. você tem certeza que ajustou o código como eu te disse? Eu acho que vc fez outra confusão.

Comment: editei novamente  a function

Comment: @VictorT. então é sem is_null, já deixei bem claro na minha resposta, se vc adicionou novamente é porque você não esta entendendo o que esta fazendo, vc esta fazendo coisas aleatorias e sem sentido, simplesmente. Eu já disse que aquilo nunca vai retornar null, logo não tem sentido usar is_null. E se sem is_null está retornando um array vazio `[]` é porque tem algo de errado na sua query, mas como eu já te disse pra esse caso vc deve abrir uma nova pergunta, pois esse é outro problema, como detalhes da tabela e dados, pois sem isso eu não tenho como te ajudar sem informações desse tipo.

Comment: ok obrigado, tentarei abrir outra pergunta, mas fiz umas edicoes na query e   agora diz que --> "Column 'descricao' in where clause is ambiguous"} é péssimo ser iniciante rs

Comment: @VictorT. isso é problema na sua query mesmo, quando fizer a pergunta me manda o link

Comment: @VictorT. antes de criar a pergunta, tenta mudar pra isto `$result = "SELECT a.descricao, a.codigo_produto, a.barcode, b.codigo_tipo, c.porcao FROM CADPRO A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOPROD B ON (A.CODIGO_PRODUTO = B.CODIGO_PRODUTO)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN INFOPROD C ON (B.CODIGO_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO_PRODUTO) WHERE a.descricao =''";` e veja se funciona.

Comment: Fiz desta forma com o a.descricao e o resultado quando vou em inspecionar e na aba Network  é este =>{"codigo_produto":"MARMEL","barcode":"3719826450","codigo_tipo":"PEDACO","porcao":"50 g"}
$result = "SELECT a.descricao, a.codigo_produto, a.barcode, b.codigo_tipo, c.porcao FROM CADPRO A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TIPOPROD B ON (A.CODIGO_PRODUTO = B.CODIGO_PRODUTO)
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFOPROD C ON (B.CODIGO_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO_PRODUTO) WHERE a.descricao =''"; mas no caso a linha que esta dentro de {...}  é justamente o que deveria retornar dentro dos inputs e seria solucionado o problema

Comment: @VictorT. ae complica, melhor abrir outra pergunta, porque da forma que está eu nem consigo saber aonde é o problema, visando que esse assunto já é totalmente outro.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar desta forma:

```
$resultado = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if(!is_null($resultado)){
     ...
```

Assumindo que você não instanciou a **classe mysqli**. Veja o exemplo nesta [página](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), interpretando seu código, aparentemente está fazendo de forma procedural.

Desta forma não poderia utilizar nenhum tipo de objeto.

Comment: Vou mostrar o código na function.php como esta agora meu erro é ------><b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\function.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
{"codigo_produto":null,"barcode":null,"codigo_tipo":null,"porcao":null}

Comment: A função mysqli_fetch_assoc retorna uma matriz associativa que corresponde a linha obtida, ou NULL se não houverem mais linhas. No caso, como não está utilizando o mysqli_num_rows, irá retornar NULL. (Em sua ultima atualização)